# How to find complementary, contiguous integer intervals in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, intervals

I have a set of integer intervals in some range, e.g. 1-20, and I would like to generate complementary, contiguous intervals to them, like so:

```
intervals <- list(3:6, 10:11, 19:20)

complementary_intervals <- list(1:2, 7:9, 12:18)
```

Alternatively, I'll have a dataframe/tibble of start and end integers:

```
library(tidyverse)

intervals <- tribble(
 ~start, ~end,
 3, 6,
 10, 11,
 19, 20
)
```

How can I find the complementary intervals? I've tried using `set_diff` to generate the integers not included in the intervals, but then I'm stuck finding contiguous intervals from those.

Comment: Try x <- `setdiff(1L:120L, unlist(intervals)); split(x, cumsum(c(1L, diff(x) != 1L)))`.

Comment: Thanks! I rewrote that to `setdiff(1L:20L, unlist(intervals)) %>% (function (x) split(x, cumsum(c(1L, diff(x) != 1L))))` - this works but I'll need to read it a couple of times to work out why!

Comment: @Friede consider posting as an answer

Comment: Of course, pipe as you like/to your needs. @Maël, thanks for the recommendation. Today is the first day I am answering questions. Not enough reputation yet to post more than one answer within 30 minutes. I will do it soon.

Comment: I missed your assignment to x above, as the `x <-` was outside the inline code - with that included your code works fine without pipes

Comment: @Friede Then, welcome to the community! Your recent comment/answers were very useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Maël's suggestion in the comments, I post my comment as an answer.

Try

```r
# data 
intervals <- list(3:6, 10:11, 19:20)
complementary_intervals <- list(1:2, 7:9, 12:18)
# task 
x <- setdiff(1L:20L, unlist(intervals)) 
( y <- split(x, cumsum(c(1L, diff(x) != 1L))) )
```

which gives

```
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

To check the result:

```
mapply(FUN = "%in%", complementary_intervals, y)
```

Of course, the two lines could be easily rewritten as piped version. This would hold the environment clean - good idea.

```r
list(3:6, 10:11, 19:20) |> 
  { \(.) setdiff(x = 1L:20L, y = unlist(.)) }() |>
  { \(.) split(x = ., f = cumsum(x = c(1L, diff(x = .) != 1L))) }()
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think the range is from 1 to 20, not to 120 ;)

Answer (score 4):

On top of @Frieke's base R solution, I'd like to bring up a `tidyverse` approach using the recent `ivs` package, which conveniently deals with intervals:

```r
library(ivs)
intervals <- tribble(
  ~start, ~end,
  3, 6,
  10, 11,
  19, 20
)

#Create the intervals (iv) object
iv1 = iv(intervals$start, intervals$end)
iv2 = iv(1, 20)

#Compute the difference
iv_set_difference(iv2, iv1)
# <iv<double>[3]>
# [1] [1, 3)   [6, 10)  [11, 19)

#You can easily transform this object back to a `normal` data.frame/tibble:
iv_diff <- iv_set_difference(iv2, iv1)
tibble(start = iv_start(iv_diff),
       end = iv_end(iv_diff))

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   start   end
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3
# 2     6    10
# 3    11    19
```

Comment: `ivs` looks interesting

Comment: Needs a speed test vs. the other answers :-)

Comment: Worth noting that in ivs 0.2.0 i did rename `iv_difference()` to `iv_set_difference()` https://github.com/DavisVaughan/ivs/blob/main/NEWS.md#ivs-020. I don't have any other name changes planned though :)

Comment: You could also use `iv_set_complement(iv(start, end), lower = 1, upper = 20)` for this particular case

Comment: submitted an edit to use the more up-to-date `iv_set_difference()`

Answer (score 1):

```
intervals <- list(3:6, 10:11, 19:20)

library(intervals)

foo <- \(intervals, domain) {
  stopifnot(length(domain) == 2L)
  intervals <- lapply(intervals, \(x) x[c(1L, length(x))])
  intervals <- c(list(c(-Inf, domain[[1]] - 1L)), 
                 intervals, 
                 list(c(domain[[2]] + 1L, Inf)))
  intervals <- do.call(rbind, intervals)  
  intervals <- Intervals(
    intervals,
    closed = c(TRUE, TRUE),
    type = "Z"
  )
  interval_complement(intervals)
}

foo(intervals, c(1L, 20L))
#Object of class Intervals
#3 intervals over Z:
#[1, 2]
#[7, 9]
#[12, 18]
```